daz to Blender bridge issue with exporting
I have installed the Daz to Blender bridge add on and it used to work fine. But now I am having some variation of this error message whenever I try to import a model animation in Blender:

If anyone has an idea why this is the case please let me know :)))

You may want to ask this at https://www.daz3d.com/forums/ or https://www.daz3d.com/forums/categories/blender-discussion
